# xrandr issues with HDMI output flip screen to mirror image

Tags: dell, xrandr

I have a Dell laptop connected via HDMI to a TV monitor. My goal is to invert the screen in such a way that it will appear as a mirror image or be read clearly in a mirror. I am creating a sort of projector and this has become a big issue. Last night I discovered `xrandr` and while I think it's probably the key to my solution I can't seem to get it to work the way I need it to.

I did `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --reflect x` to mirror/flip mine and it kind of worked but shut off my laptop screen. Is there any way to flip/mirror HDMI output so that I can still use my laptop screen as well?

Comment: You should be able to set each screen orientation (independently) via Ubuntu settings `Screen Display` section. What happens when you set/change orientation there?

Comment: I tried that, and it did work, but not to the display setting I want. I'm aiming for a teleprompter style setting but on the whole desktop and not a teleprompter. I need something you can read in a mirror.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your post properly. Have you tried combining xrandr parameters to define settings for both screens in one command? Like: `xrandr --output eDP-1 auto --output HDMI-1 --reflect x` (eDP-1 is valid for my laptop screen, it may be different for yours). Perhaps this is a limitation of the hardware or drivers (not being able to reflect a single screen).

Comment: So you totally solved 1/2 of my problem :) you're already a huge help. Now how do I run the code you just gave but still keep my primary LVDS-1 laptop screen active? that's the second piece of my puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually figured it out with everyone's help. My problem was I wasn't setting it like a dual screen. It was only working as if there was one screen. So to adapt @codlord's code I used: 'xandr --output LVDS-1 --auto --output HDMI-1 --reflect x --right-of LVDS-1'.  That worked like a charm :)